# Is there any way to keep information safe in an Android apk?

Tags: java, android

AFAIK Android decompilation allows one to extract every bit of information from an apk.
How can I store information like ftp passwords or other confidential strings in Java or any other XML file? Is there any way other than calling a service?

EDIT Problem:

```
String uname = "mks";
    String part1="pass";
    String part2="my";
    String part3="word";
```

As per David answer i obfuscating a string but after dcompilation i able to see my password

```
 String[] arrayOfString = new String[2]; arrayOfString[0] = "mks"; arrayOfString[1] = ("my" + "pass" + "word");
```

Comment: The best you can do is to encrypt the data and obfuscate the code. But don't store any sensitive info on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about obfuscating a string here. One of the easiest ways to accomplish this is to split it up into multiple parts in your code, and then combine these together to make the final result. All your strings are still present, but they will be hard to put back together again.

For example, if the password you're trying to hide is "102938475601", here's one way to do it:

```
// Declare the parts
String part2 = "3847";
String part1 = "1029";
String part3 = "5601";

// Log in to the server
ftpServer.sendLogin("username", part1+part2+part3);
```

This is a very simple form of obfuscation. If you're more keen on protecting the data, you could try additional methods such as encrypting the password with a non-standard form of encryption, and splitting the key up as described above.

But ultimately you're correct - there's no guaranteed way to package data in an Android app without it being accessible to anyone who decompiles the app. All you can do is make it *harder* for them to interpret whatever data they can find.

Comment: if user get the java file by extracting the apk file?

Comment: They can't reverse engineer your variable names. They'll basically just have bytecode which does a whole heap of variable manipulations, so it will be hard to spot things like this. Even harder if you use ProGuard.

Comment: hey Look at this...i dcomplied it i could able to see my pass word   String[] arrayOfString = new String[2];
        arrayOfString[0] = "mds";
        arrayOfString[1] = ("my" + "pass" + "word"); what you say now?

Comment: for this to have chance to "work" you need String part = new String("12345"); this way in place where it is used it will be one indirection away = not far enough, so it does not actualy work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of encryption. Then obfuscate the encryption keys by some calculation so that they are not *easily* retrievable by reverse engineering efforts. Make sure the keys and decrypted data is disposed immediately after usage.

If you retrieve the passwords through network, using authentication and SSL and obfuscated URLS in the source code, then you can detect attempts to retrieve the passwords and ban the connections from that source. But this is much added effort and introduces potential problem if your server is down.

Answer (score 0):

If they are important data, NEVER keep it on your code, things like credentials to FTP services and so on.

Obfuscation is only going to add a little bit of difficulty. The best way is to do a request to a WS (of course, https and with signature) and the answer to be this credentials.

The other solution (better than obfuscation or splitting the string on your JAVA code) is to have this information into a native library and access it on real time using the JNI interface.